# I am using android paging library but rather than getting data in chunks I am getting complete list in one go

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

ViewModel class inside which we are loading pagedlist using data source.

```
    public class RecipeListViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public LiveData<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>> mutableLiveData;

    public void init(RecipeFrom recipeFrom, RecipeDao recipeDao) {
    mutableLiveData = new 
    LivePagedListBuilder(recipeDao.getRecipeList(),10).build();
   }
   }
```

This is my dao in which we are fetching data in form of datasource factory.

```
   @Dao
   public interface RecipeDao {
   @Query("select * from recipe")
   public DataSource.Factory<Integer, RecipeListPojo> getRecipeList();
   }
```

Inside my RecipeListPojo I have created the DiffCallBack.

```
   public static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RecipeListPojo> diffCallback=new 
   DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RecipeListPojo>() {
   @Override
   public boolean areItemsTheSame(RecipeListPojo oldItem, RecipeListPojo 
   newItem) {
   return oldItem.getId()==newItem.getId();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean areContentsTheSame(RecipeListPojo oldItem, RecipeListPojo 
   newItem) {
   return oldItem.equals(newItem);
   }
   };
```

Inside my activity i am reciveing the pagedlist through observer and setting my adapter.

```
  arrayListObserver=new Observer<PagedList<RecipeListPojo>>() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<RecipeListPojo> recipePojos) {

  if(recipePojos!=null)
  {
  recipeAdapter.submitList(recipePojos);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(recipeAdapter);
  progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
  }
  }
  };
  recipeFrom=new RecipeFrom.RecipeFromBuilder(fromActivity).build();
  recipeDao=GlobalApplication.recipeRoomDatabase.getRecipeDao();
  recipeListViewModel.init(recipeFrom,recipeDao);
  recipeListViewModel.mutableLiveData.observe(this,arrayListObserver);
```

This is how my adapter looks like.

```
  public class RecipeListAdapter extends 
  PagedListAdapter<RecipeListPojo,RecipeListAdapter.RecipeListHolder> {

  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private Context context;

  public RecipeListAdapter()
  {
  super(RecipeListPojo.diffCallback);
  }

  @Override
  public RecipeListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
  {

  context=parent.getContext();
  inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_item_recipe_list, null, 
  false);
  return new RecipeListHolder(rootView);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
  return super.getItemCount();
  }
  }
```

Library used-

```
  // Paging
  implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-rc1"
```

Comment: where do you use `mutableLiveData`? i see it only in `RecipeListViewModel`, what do you need `arrayListObserver` for? why dont you follow the sample code in `PagedListAdapter` documentation?

Comment: arrayListObserver is observing the mutableLiveData inside the activity, then only observer is getting the pagedlist

Comment: did you see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter? it simply uses: `viewModel.usersList.observe(this, pagedList -> adapter.submitList(pagedList));` - just do the same

Comment: It's actually same .

Comment: what does `Log.d(TAG, "size: " + recipePojos.size());` show?

Comment: its showing the total no. of elements in my list rather than the pages size (10) that i have defined while creating the paged list .

Comment: I am not able to find this adapter.submitList(pagedList) , because i am using // Paging
  implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha4-1"

Comment: ok how many rows do you have? more than 30? (3*10)

Comment: I have 1300 rows

Comment: ok try `Log.d(TAG, "list: " + recipePojos);` notice that you will see 30 "real" items and 1270 `null`s - i hope you will know what it means

Comment: Thanks @pskink yes you are right , I got only 30 objects , rest are nulls

Comment: do you know where 30 comes from?

Comment: Yeah because I have given limit of 10 items , so 10 previous, 10 current and 10 next items.

Comment: [setInitialLoadSizeHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Config.Builder.html#setInitialLoadSizeHint(int)) *"If not set, defaults to three times page size."*

Comment: I would suggest one of you to add an answer to this question, since it's now solved

Answer (score 4):

As per my research, 
I have finally found that It returns a list of size = total no. of items, but only pagedList size * 3 will be initialized and rest items will be nulls,
and they will be updated while scrolling the recyclerView using PagedListAdapter .

Comment: Good find..!! But the rest of the items are not loading while scrolling the recyclerview.Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT2:

> its showing the total no. of elements in my list rather than the pages size (10) that i have defined while creating the paged list

Use `setEnablePlaceholders(false)`

---

*Previous answer:*

After wondering about this myself and reading through the comments and answers, I found out it has to with the config you set. More specifically the `PageSize`.

If you set it to 1, and scroll really fast, you'll see placeholders, meaning all the data isn't load yet.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Config.Builder):

> **setPageSize**
>
> Defines the number of items loaded at once from the DataSource.
>
> Should be several times the number of visible items onscreen.
>
> Configuring your page size depends on how your data is being loaded
>   and used. Smaller page sizes improve memory usage, latency, and avoid
>   GC churn. Larger pages generally improve loading throughput, to a
>   point (avoid loading more than 2MB from SQLite at once, since it
>   incurs extra cost).
>
> If you're loading data for very large, social-media style cards that
>   take up most of a screen, and your database isn't a bottleneck, 10-20
>   may make sense. If you're displaying dozens of items in a tiled grid,
>   which can present items during a scroll much more quickly, consider
>   closer to 100.

P.S. Try not to use `setInitialLoadSizeHint` unless you really need it because it will run on the UI thread even if you've specified a `fetchExecutor` on a background thread.